# insert in select in MySQL with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I would like to have a value from a row inserted into an other row here is my code:

```
static void addVipMonth(String name) throws SQLException
{
    Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    PreparedStatement queryStatement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO vips(memberId, gotten, expires) " +
            "VALUES (SELECT name FROM members WHERE id = ?, NOW(), DATEADD(month, 1, NOW()))"); //Put your query in the quotes
    queryStatement.setString(1, name);
    queryStatement.executeUpdate(); //Executes the query
    queryStatement.close(); //Closes the query
    conn.close(); //Closes the connection
}
```

This code is not valid. How do I correct it?

Comment: It is not valid how? BTW: You should almost never have a need to cast to `Connection` or `PreparedStatement` as the methods already return those (from the package `java.sql`), it might be a sign you are using the wrong types for your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get an error `17:28:46 [SEVERE] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MyS QL server version for the right syntax to use near ' NOW(), DATE_ADD( now(), INT ERVAL 1 MONTH )' at line 1` –  sanchixx

It was due to error in `SELECT ..` statement.
Modified statement is:

```
INSERT INTO vips( memberId, gotten, expires )  
   SELECT name, NOW(), DATE_ADD( now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
    FROM members WHERE id = ?
```

---

1. You don't require `VALUES` key word when `inserting` with a `select`.
2. You used a wrong `DATEADD` function syntax. Correct syntax is `Date_add( date_expr_or_col, INTERVAL number unit_on_interval)`.

You can try your insert statement as corrected below:

```
INSERT INTO vips( memberId, gotten, expires )  
   SELECT name FROM members
     WHERE id = ?, NOW(), DATE_ADD( now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```

Refer to:

1. **[INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html)**
2. **[DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)**

Comment: I get an error `17:28:46 [SEVERE] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You
 have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MyS
QL server version for the right syntax to use near ' NOW(), DATE_ADD( now(), INT
ERVAL 1 MONTH )' at line 1`